# What parameters can be used to configure context-sensitive authorisation?

Tags: authorization, owasp, asvs

I recognise that context-sensitive authorisation to applications is a good security control however I can currently only think of location being an example of a sensitive context.

I don't consider time being a sensitive context so are there any other examples?

Comment: Time can be: "employees can only access content during their scheduled shifts" is a perfectly valid access control.

Comment: Agree of course! I think it would be classified as non-sensitive though so just context authorisation rather than context-senstive authorisation? No?

Comment: .... hmm, I don't think I know the difference between the buzz-words "context authorization" vs "context-sensitive authorization".

Answer (score 1):

Context-sensative in this case just means that the context is take into account. It has nothing to do with *location* being a "sensative" or "secret" attribute.

There's a lot of potential contexts which can be used to aid in authorization.

Location and time are by far the most common.

E.X.

- Is the request coming from the corporate network?
- Is the user VPNed in?
- What is the GPS location of the user?
- Is this normal business hours?
- How many of these requests have been made in the last N hours?

Context authorization usually also includes roles, which can be implemented using RBAC.